# Remove whitespace in print function

Tags: python

I have this code

```
print "/*!",your_name.upper(),"*/";
```

where your_name is the data the user inputs.

How can I edit the code above to tell the system to remove any whitespace?

UPDATE:

If i print the code, i'll get
    /*! your_name */

I want to remove the whitspaces between /*! your_name */

Comment: Remove **what** whitespace? The spaces inserted by `print` when you use multiple expressions separated by commas?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The whitspaces between /*! your_name */

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces are inserted by the `print` statement when you pass in multiple expressions separated by commas. Don't use the commas, but build *one string*, so you pass in just the one expression:

```
print "/*!" + your_name.upper() + "*/"
```

or use string formatting with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "/*!{0}*/".format(your_name.upper())
```

or the older [string formatting operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
print "/*!%s*/" % your_name.upper()
```

Or use the [`print()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), setting the separator to an empty string:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("/*!", your_name.upper(), "*/", sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The white spaces are inserted by print when you use multiple expressions separated by commas.

Instead of using commas, try :

```
print "/*!" + your_name.upper() + "*/"
```